# Qt Quick Controls 2 UWP CommandBar implementation

Tags: win-universal-app, qt5, qtquickcontrols2

I want to implement [CommandBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) from UWP design such as here:

[image: CommandBar]

I didn't found accepted solutions, therefore, I think how to implement my own implementation.
Main problems for me:

1. How to implement moving buttons to menu if width not enough for displaying all buttons?
2. How to implement item control cascade for filling him?

Comment: @Mitch I tried standard toolbar from qt quick controls 2. Second question mean, if I will implement this control such as independent component, how I can to fill him?

Comment: Looks to me as a notification area here: https://youtu.be/fUGHhGWDNB0?t=2m15s Buttons are movable and minimized by default . Sources for that are available, but it's for an actual thing, so they can be overwhelming: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/unity8/vivid/files/head:/qml/Panel/

Comment: @Velkan thank you for link, looks good, but not that I really need. You can see https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars description of control that I want to have in qt.

Comment: I mean, how have you tried to fill the toolbar? Where's your code that shows what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Mitch I just want control in qt such as here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars or very similar